# Javascript function is hijacking spacebar key

Tags: javascript

I'm using Firefox and I'd like to know how I can determine which function on a site that uses Javascript interrupts the normal operation of <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> key, which is supposed to scroll down a whole page (and in combo with <kbd>Shift</kbd> scoll up a page), and super-hijack it to work normally. How do I do that?

I don't want to disable Javascript on the whole site or everywhere, so Noscript is not a solution. I'm looking for disabling a single function.

Comment: Apparently there are script disabling extensions that allow for selective disabling, not just everything.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome:

Open DevTools, choose `Sources` tab, on the right side expand `Event Listener Breakpoints`, here you choose `Keyboard`, and select `keyup` or `keydown`. Then use the website, it'll break on keyup or keydown, so you just have to press spacebar to find out where it's handled.

Comment: Well, I'm using Firefox :\

Comment: @user1306322: You only need to do it once to find out where in the script it's doing it so you can pinpoint where you need override the event handler. So install Chrome, do all of the above, then write a greasemonkey script for Firefox based on the info.

Comment: @user1306322: Firebug has similar capabilities

Comment: Firefox has built-in inspector with debugger, I just need to know what exactly I should be looking for. So far I couldn't find an explicit option to track all keyboard events, but maybe there are several common way to figure out which function has to to with key events and spacebar key specifically. But I bet it's easier if I just install chrome and use its tools *sigh*.

Comment: And now it turns out this script doesn't work in Chrome, so I can't find the function that ruins my couch-browsing experience in Firefox with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

use Jonathan's answer to find what the issue is, but this will, as you call it, "super-hijack" it (probably):

```
function cancelUtil(e){
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
window.addEventListener('keydown',cancelUtil,true);
window.addEventListener('keypress',cancelUtil,true);
window.addEventListener('keyup',cancelUtil,true);
```